powerbi custom visual tutorial not calling the update constructor
I am very new to the world of power bi custom visuals. What I did is follow a tutorial to get started on this journey using the official power bi YouTube channel. Basically, it will ask to create a project using the new parameter
pbiviz new helloWorld
Then you simply go ahead and type in
pbiviz start
I did both the steps and am able to see the constructor method being called without any issue. But when I re-size to update the count, the update constructor is not being called. Here I am not sure if something else needs to be called as well. I am sharing the code here of visual.ts:
/*
*  Power BI Visual CLI
*
*  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
*  All rights reserved.
*  MIT License
*
*  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
*  of this software and associated documentation files (the ""Software""), to deal
*  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
*  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
*  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
*  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
*  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
*  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
*  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED *AS IS*, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
*  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
*  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
*  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
*  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
*  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
*  THE SOFTWARE.
*/
"use strict";

import powerbi from "powerbi-visuals-api";
import { FormattingSettingsService } from "powerbi-visuals-utils-formattingmodel";
import "./../style/visual.less";

import VisualConstructorOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualConstructorOptions;
import VisualUpdateOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualUpdateOptions;
import IVisual = powerbi.extensibility.visual.IVisual;

import { VisualFormattingSettingsModel } from "./settings";

export class Visual implements IVisual {
    private target: HTMLElement;
    private updateCount: number;
    private textNode: Text;
    private formattingSettings: VisualFormattingSettingsModel;
    private formattingSettingsService: FormattingSettingsService;

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        console.log('Visual constructor', options);
        this.formattingSettingsService = new FormattingSettingsService();
        this.target = options.element;
        this.updateCount = 0;
        if (document) {
            const new_p: HTMLElement = document.createElement("p");
            new_p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Update count:"));
            const new_em: HTMLElement = document.createElement("em");
            this.textNode = document.createTextNode(this.updateCount.toString());
            new_em.appendChild(this.textNode);
            new_p.appendChild(new_em);
            this.target.appendChild(new_p);
        }
    }

    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        this.formattingSettings = this.formattingSettingsService.populateFormattingSettingsModel(VisualFormattingSettingsModel, options.dataViews[0]);
 
        console.log('Visual update', options);
        if (this.textNode) {
            this.textNode.textContent = (this.updateCount++).toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns properties pane formatting model content hierarchies, properties and latest formatting values, Then populate properties pane.
     * This method is called once every time we open properties pane or when the user edit any format property. 
     */
    public getFormattingModel(): powerbi.visuals.FormattingModel {
        return this.formattingSettingsService.buildFormattingModel(this.formattingSettings);
    }
}

Can someone please help me why the update method doesn't work. I re-size the visual box as per the tutorial but it doesn't update the counts.
Here is the link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQB-q9SVyY4
